# Tsx files are not getting compile with swc?

Tags: typescript, compilation, nestjs, tsx, swc

I have the following swc configuration in place, but when I compile them with nest.js swc, the tsx files are not compiled at all and no artifact is created for them.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  },
  "jsc": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "tsx": true,
      "decorators": true,
      "dynamicImport": true,
    },
    "transform": {
      "legacyDecorator": true,
      "decoratorMetadata": true,
      "react": {
        "refresh": true
      }
    },
    "keepClassNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "minify": false
}
```

Trying to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Set the extensions in your `nest-cli.json` file.

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "builder": {
    "type": "swc",
    "options": {
      "extensions": [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this helps solve the question asked, including links such as to documentation